# Can Custom Notification Styles Include Base Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications

I have the need to build a custom notification style for expanded views of notifications. However I want to take advantage of some of the base notification styles, specifically the icon_group that is setup and used by the base notification layouts.

Is there a way to inherit these layout definitions somehow instead of copying the base layouts and related properties and effectively "forking" the layout as it exists today in SDK?

Here is the piece I want to include in my custom notification style thinking that this will work (or really I just want it to work). This code is in notification_template_marterial_big_base.xml and notification_template_material_base.xml and would like it to also exist within my custom layouts.

```
<include layout="@layout/notification_template_icon_group"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_large_icon_height" />
```

Comment: Well, the sizes appear in [the JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.dimen.html), so `@android:dimen/...` may work for those. The layout is not, though, so I think you're out of luck there. Also bear in mind that device manufacturers and Google can tinker with these things.

Comment: yes getting the dimen is pretty nice that it is available, however I really wish I could just get the layout itself... yeah true that manufacturers can change this

Comment: another thing that I would love to be able to do is to insert something in a "big" notification layout, but still be able to use the base layout styles and builder for most things instead of having a remoteviews taking over the entire notification layout